# How to run Apache benchmark load-test in Windows?

Tags: apache, benchmarking

what's the procedure I should follow to run a simple test on a domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)? I'm on Windows environment and have installed WAMP server 2.1.

I actually know which command I should use (Ex. `ab -n 1 http://www.example.com/`) but don't know where I should type it.

Comment: For load testing your web server you need a load testing tool. There are a large number of them available, and each of them is used in their own way. You mentioned which command you are going to run. Is it because you already have selected the tool and basically asking how to use it, or you need recommendation on what tool to pick?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't know the path WampServer is installed to, so I'll just show you how I do it under WampDeveloper (which is what I use).

Run cmd.exe.

Inside...

```
C:
cd \WampDeveloper\Components\Apache\bin
ab -n 1 http://www.example.com/
```

To answer your question, you type it in the command line changed to the bin folder of your Apache folder since this is where ab.exe exists.  If this folder location is in the system path, you can also just type it in anywhere (without changing paths in cmd.exe).

This 1st line changes the drive letter. Then second the path (aka working directory). The third runs ab.exe.

Answer (score 2):

I do agree, `PATH ENVIRONMENT` setup manually

```
C:/YOUR_INSTALLATION_APACHE2/bin
```

Path to environment on control panel system settings.

Comment: @ Faizal, What are you trying to suggest to OP. -5